# Item_person_HoverPanel

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, hover-panel

I have created a custom search.  I created my own folder in the Display Templates for Results and item person which seem to be working fine.  I copied a hoverpanel into the same directory but no matter what changes I make nothing changes.  How do I know which hoverpanel the results are using?  The hoverpanel I have keeps showing Authored Documents which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Click on search Web part and Edit Web part to check which DisPlay template is being used.

[image]

Here is an article about steps to create custom display templates and use it:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-display-templates-in-sharepoint-2013/